# Event driven message routing and hiding implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I need to sent messages around my program to different class libraries. So the way I thought it does this was to have a message router class that all the different libraries subscribe to and all messages go through the router.

To send a message an event is raised in the sender asynchronously which the message router is listening to. So I have got the message to the message router. Then the message router raises another event on the receiver asynchronously.

a) Is this the correct way to do such a thing?

b) How can I hide the implementation so that the class only has a `MessageReceived(string message)` and `SendMessage(string message)` method.

Now I could create an abstract class but to "hide" the implementation of the events I would have to implement the add and remove which I am trying to avoid. If that is the only way, how do I implement that add/remove in a thread safe way?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of sounds like an Event Aggregator. This question may help you - [Event Aggregator Implementation Sample / Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices).

Comment: Are events even the best way to go for something like this?

Comment: It depends what you mean by events. For example, the [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework implements an [Event Aggregator](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Event%20Aggregator) class that makes it very simple to publish and subscribe to events. This allows for a certain amount of decoupling between the sender and receiver. These events shouldn't be confused with the standard .Net events.

Comment: Whenever I have referred to an event in the OP, I meant literally a .NET event object.

Comment: I'd encourage you to look into the event aggregator patterns mentioned in answers to the linked questions. The fact that so many frameworks make use of an event aggregator rather than using standard events imply there are benefits to be had.